# RegEx: Match a character and (possibly) the one before

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex that matches a particular character and if and only if the character before is a space, match it as well.

E.g.: the character I am looking for is "a", then in "this is a test" there should " a" be matched (including the space).

Since there is no logical "and", how do you do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: `\s?a`? That should work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? with space or without space.

Comment: The space and the a should both be matched. At the moment I just have them matched seperatly.

Comment: If a and the space must be matched **if and only if** the space is also present, you have to match the string " a", so the regexp might be / a/ (I have delimited with slashes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this expression:

```
[ ]?a
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/e8EYerurxXbPvwlS)

I made a character class from a space **[ ]** to improve readability. I did not use **\s** because QE requested explicitly a space match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the OR condition.

used this way in your case :

/(a| a)/

For more informations, you can find some here :
http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/or-in-regex/